# My flutter Singleton keeps fogetting all it's data

Tags: android, flutter

so I'm kind of new to Flutter, and I'm trying to do a small project to learn a bit, and I've stumbled upon a problem that's been making me bash my head against the keyboard for a bit.

I've made a Singleton class, which stores some data about the user, and its like this:

```
class GaurController {
  static final GaurController _instance = GaurController._internal(); 
  static const String _url = "https://gestion-servicios.ehu.es/gaurMovilRS/rest";
  final http.Client _client = http.Client();
  static const _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  String? _authToken;
  String? _ldap;
  String? _pass;
  UserProfile? profile;


  factory GaurController() => _instance;

  GaurController._internal();
```

My main file is like this

```dart
import 'package:bihar/model/gaur_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bihar/login.dart';
import 'package:bihar/homepage.dart';
import 'package:bihar/splashpage.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GaurController().init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashPage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/splash":(context) => SplashPage(),
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => const Login(),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The splashpage loads the data, and if no stored credentials are available, it launches the /login route with `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home')`.
After this, the Singleton keeps all of its stored data, but, after a succesful login, the login page again launches the /home route, and inside it, when I call any of the singleton class's methods, it is like a new instance, with all the stored data in it's attributes set to null. Any idea of what could be causing this? I can provide more code if neccesary, this is all the code that I think might be neccesary, but of course, I'm new to flutter, so feel free to correct me.

Thanks in advanced!

I've tried using the 'get_it' package, but it also gives me errors. It worked correctly until I tried to get the instance in the HomePage, where it fails telling me that no object of that class has been registered

Comment: You should make a variable of that singleton and use that variable everywhere. Because if you just use the class instance then it wont be available in other places.

Comment: Are you sure you are not clearing the data anywhere? maybe some logout function being triggered that does it?

Comment: Where could I make that variable that is accesible anywhere?

Comment: I'm not clearing the data, I've looked at it step by step in the debugger and it only clears when entering the code in the HomePage class

Comment: Check this example: https://flutterdesk.com/flutter-singleton/

Comment: @WilsonToribio their way of doing it is literally the same. It's the "Singleton with Factory Constructor"

Comment: To me your code looks fine. Maybe you could add a body to your `_internal` constructor and put a print there to see if it's really being called more than once

Comment: Would you show where and how the Singleton is being used?

Comment: Can you also show us how you import at the top your files looks like?

Comment: After adding the log statement, yes it's being built multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. I was importing like `import 'package:bihar/model/GAUR_Controller.dart';` in the homepage file,
but that wasn't the correct name of the file, and that was causing the problem.
It's really weird and I can't really understand why that make the class build twice though, if someone has some possible insight I'd love to hear it.